# How to allow only X axis rotation of 3D model? (SceneKit)

Tags: xamarin, 3d, xamarin.ios, scenekit

I've  an app that should show a 3D model, at this point all is OK, but this model rotates in all 3D space axis and I need that this model rotate only on X axis (left/right) when user tries rotate the model.

Any idea? I've been stuck here for a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide your own camera. Don't use the "allows camera control" checkbox in Interface Builder, and leave the view's `allowsCameraControl` property set to `false`.

You said "X axis (left/right)". But in SceneKit, the X axis runs left to right, so rotating left/right is a rotation around the Y axis. Add a swipe gesture recognizer to recognize swipes left and right. Use the recognizer's handler to rotate your model around the Y axis as the user's finger slides left and right.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to simply limit the default camera controller's minimumVerticalAngle to 90 degrees and set the interactionMode to orbitTurntable

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
    let view = SCNView()
    view.allowsCameraControl = true
    view.defaultCameraController.minimumVerticalAngle = 90
    view.defaultCameraController.interactionMode = .orbitTurntable
    return view
}
```

This worked fine for me

Comment: Not sure why exactly minimumVerticalAngle works instead of maximumVerticalAngle, but it is what it is

Comment: this is a great answer and works correctly. (ignore the maximumVerticalAngle and you are all good with the view.allowsCameraControl feature) tnx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SCNTransformConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scntransformconstraint).

You can specify a SCNTransformConstraint as a value in the [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1408016-constraints) property of the SCNNode to which the geometry is assigned.